# WCF Service (JSON) and Android client - message security

Tags: java, android, wcf, security

I have WCF service, that gets and returns JSON data. and Android mobile app, that calls this service.

- How do I encrypt messages between these two, if possible?
- If not, how to do custom encryption?

**Edit:**

Here is an additional information for server and client sides.

The service looks next:

**Service interface**:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ITest

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
    Function Test(header As RequestHeader, body As TestRequestResponse) As Boolean

End Interface
```

**Service code**

```
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
<ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)>
Public Class TestService
    Implements ITest

    Public Function Test(header As RequestHeader, body As TestRequestResponse) As Boolean Implements ITest.Test

        Return True

    End Function

End Class
```

**Web.Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="RMWS.TestBehavior" name="RMWS.TestService">
            <endpoint address="Test" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" contract="RMWS.ITest" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RMWS.TestBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug  includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client call**

The client call currently made from javascript for testing only. In future a client will be android app, but the general idea is same.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/RMWS/TestService.svc/Test/Test",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(somedata),
    success: function (data)
    {
        ...
    },
    error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**Edit 2:**

I know it can be done easily with SSL. But in my company thinks it's too expensive for performance and traffic, so they don't want to use SSL, and instead do some other encryption. If possible, only requests may be encoded, as responses doesn't contain any sensitive info.

**Edit 3:**

Any other opinions except Joseph's answer?

Comment: Please update your question and give us more information: how is your client connecting to your service?  What have you tried, etc.

Comment: @Terry Donaghe: See question's update please

Answer (score 1):

SSL is the best bet if you want to carry on using JSON, you could obfuscate JSON but that would no longer be JSON and would be silly and would still be accessible to those who are really interested.

Your best bet is to send binary over to the device, you could encrypt that using pgp but the problem you would then have is storing a private key in an android app which in itself isn't very secure.

SSL is the safest bet.

Comment: Do you know what difference in SSL vs other encryption in traffic/performance? Is this difference worse to implement something other than SSL?

Comment: The difference is how much YOUR time is worth. SSL is a known solution, whereas you'll have to rewrite you client server which is an unknown quantity.

Comment: Agree with you. But to know if it worth, I want to understand how much time/effort is to use other, than SSL, encryption. I'm not guru in service security, so want to know is it something, that can be done in 1 hour, or will take weeks of work.

Comment: SSL 1 hour. not SSL who knows, you could take 2 or 3 days to make something you think is secure and then get hacked anyway.

Comment: SSL certificates cost as little a $9 nowadays, it's not worth the effort looking for a worse solution. you can even self sign for free. What is the point going for a non-industry standard solution.